# Create feature datasets from group layer name

Tags: arcpy, group-layer, feature-dataset

Is it possible to create feature dataset, based on the name from group layers. I have two separate codes, one for finding out the names of group layers, and other to create feature datasets.

```
>>> import arcpy
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.isGroupLayer == True:
    if lyr.longName.find('\\') == -1:
    print lyr.longName
```

This is the code for searching the name of datasets, and this is the code to create feature datasets.

```
>>> arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    fdList  = ["Dataset_A", "Dataset_B", "Dataset_C"]
    folList = ["D:\\GIS_Temp\Folder A", "D:\\GIS_Temp\\Folder B", "D:\\GIS_Temp\\Folder C"]
    workRange = range(len(fdList))
    for thisIndex in workRange:
    fd = fdList[thisIndex]
    arcpy.env.workspace = folList[thisIndex]
    arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management("D:\\GIS_Temp\\TEST.gdb", fd, "D:\\GIS_Temp\\Projection.prj")
    for impFC in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    fcName,fcExt = os.path.splitext(impFC)
    fcName.replace(" ","_")
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(os.path.join(folList[thisIndex],impFC),os.path.join("D:\\GIS_Temp\\TEST.gdb",fd),fcName)
```

Is it possible to merge the two codes, into one, so the name `fdList  = ["Dataset_A", "Dataset_B", "Dataset_C"]`, would actually be names returned from the group layers based on the first code? I am trying to merge these two codes, so the searched names would actually be names of datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lyr.longName` is what you want to use to name your Feature Dataset, then you can just create an empty list `fdList = []` and append it with the `lyr.longName` to pass as FD name later.

```
import arcpy, os
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

fdList = []

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.isGroupLayer == True:
        if lyr.longName.find('\\') == -1:
        print lyr.longName
        fdList.append(lyr.longName)

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

folList = ["D:\\GIS_Temp\Folder A", "D:\\GIS_Temp\\Folder B", "D:\\GIS_Temp\\Folder C"]

workRange = range(len(fdList))

for thisIndex in workRange:
    fd = fdList[thisIndex]
    arcpy.env.workspace = folList[thisIndex]
    arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management("D:\\GIS_Temp\\TEST.gdb", fd, "D:\\GIS_Temp\\Projection.prj")

    for impFC in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
        fcName,fcExt = os.path.splitext(impFC)
        fcName.replace(" ","_")
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion( os.path.join(folList[thisIndex], impFC), os.path.join("D:\\GIS_Temp\\TEST.gdb", fd), fcName)
```

---

Please note I haven't debugged the rest of your script, so if it works for you then making the `fdList=[]` change in the script should work.

Comment: Sadly, this is not working. It just keeps giving "File "<string>", line 11, in <module>. NameError: name 'fdList' is not defined". And I did leave it empty first, and I also put  fdlist = [lyr.longName] also, but nothing. Is it maybe the problem in this line "fd = fdList[thisIndex]"?

Comment: rename the `fdlist = []` I gave you to be `fdList = []` (note the uppercase `L`), and also change `fdlist.append(lyr.longName)` to `fdList.append(lyr.longName)`

Comment: I have fixed the typo in my answer.  Python is picky when it comes to case

Comment: That part of code seems to be working now. I really also missed the uppercase problem. This part of code seems to be working, but now it gives "File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined" error, when I put code you compiled.

Comment: add `os` to the import line.  I've updated answer - `import arcpy, os`

Comment: Yes, this is it now. In this code, you really answered more than one questions I had, because I had this problem in other codes. I am still a rookie.

Comment: I think the best way to learn is to just give it a go and ask when you get stuck